# How to install Microsoft Exchange 2007 as a member server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2007

I am trying to install Microsoft Exchange 2007 to a Windows Server 2003 as a member server.  I already have a Windows Server 2008 as my domain controller.  I'm having a hard time figuring out what is needed to prepare the machine for Exchange 2007 installation.  My specific question is: While following the procedures here in the [TechNet Library](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125224%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)
, do I still need to go through with the section "How to Prepare Active Directory and Domains" and do the following commands if I am making it a member server and NOT a domain controller?
ie.. setup /ps
setup /p /on:
setup /PrepareDomain:

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you still need to follow those steps.  Exchange integrates into Active Directory and those steps prepare the schema to allow Exchange to function.  You don't need to promote your Exchange server to a domain controller.

The command to make a Windows 2003 server a domain controller is called 'dcpromo', which isn't referenced in the article you linked to.  All of the steps in the article simply add the required attributes to the objects in your Active Directory so Exchange be installed.